Flow in vent of a pipe
I have a horizontal pipe of diameter 2000mm (uniform cross section), the pressure of gas flowing in the pipe is 1.2bar and the flow velocity is 15m/sec. there is a 100mm diameter vertical vent attached to the pipe, the height of vent is 3000mm. Now I have 2 questions

If the top of the vent is sealed, will the pressure inside the vent be same as the horizontal pipe?
If the vent is open to atmosphere, are the flow velocity calculations I did correct?


I'm not sure what you did here.  What you need to do is determine static pressure at the vent (based on head loss), then the flow rate through the vent given inlet pressure plus expected head loss.  Fluid flowing in a pipe does not have uniform pressure.
